# Unable to send text and Enter key to this special textarea of this site

Tags: javascript, html, css

On [chatbot.theb.ai](https://chatbot.theb.ai/) I am trying to send `Hello, World!` to the textarea element with the class `n-input__textarea-el` and then send the `Enter` key
[image]

using this code:

```js
const element = document.querySelector('textarea.n-input__textarea-el');
element.value = 'Hello, World!';

const enterKeyEvent = new KeyboardEvent('keydown', {
  key: 'Enter',
  code: 'Enter',
  which: 13,
  keyCode: 13,
  charCode: 13,
  bubbles: true,
  cancelable: true,
});
element.dispatchEvent(enterKeyEvent);
```

, but after the code finishes executing I get this instead:

[image]

It seems the `Enter` key is not being sent, hence the text is not submitted in the chat. I've checked what is the content of textarea by using this code, trying to figure out what was happening:

```js
const textarea = document.querySelector("textarea.n-input__textarea-el");
const content = textarea.value;
console.log(content);
```

getting `Hello, World!` in the console.

I've tried the first code with different textareas (on different sites), and the code runs properly, sending both the text and the Enter key. I assume something is different with this textarea and I don't know what it is.

Can anyone give me some hints? Thanks!

Comment: It said ```element.value = 'Hello, World!';```. What is this **element**? Is this your text area also that currentry accepting text input from user? where to post the text or value after press enter??